# Office AddIn button's icon won't show up

Tags: manifest, office-addins

Here's extract from the manifest's Host

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
    <CustomTab id="MyTab">
        <Group id="Raporty.GroupPabcd">
            <Label resid="Raporty.GroupPabcd.Label" />
            <Icon>
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_16" size="16" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_20" size="20" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_24" size="24" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_32" size="32" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_40" size="40" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_48" size="48" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_64" size="64" />
                <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_80" size="80" />
            </Icon>

            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="RaportPabcd.Button">
                <Label resid="RaportPabcd.Button.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="RaportPabcd.Button.Label" />
                    <Description resid="RaportPabcd.Button.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_16" size="16" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_20" size="20" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_24" size="24" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_32" size="32" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_40" size="40" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_48" size="48" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_64" size="64" />
                    <bt:Image resid="Raporty.Icon1_80" size="80" />
                </Icon>

                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                </Action>
            </Control>

        </Group>
        <Label resid="Raporty.Tab.Label" />
    </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

as well as the resources

```
<Resources>
    <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_20" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_20.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_24" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_24.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_40" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_40.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_48" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_48.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_64" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Raporty.Icon1_80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_80.png" />
    </bt:Images>
</Resources>
```

Problem is that the button shows the default icon

[image]

I tried to access the image directly in the browser (i.e. http://localhost/ExcelWebWeb/Images/ReportIcons/report_1_32.png) and it does show up

I have taken a look at the IIS logs to see if the image was even queried by the Excel app, but it wasn't. I can only see access logs from my local browser to the icons while the addin only queries the html/js files (for the TaskPane) without querying for the button's image.

Comment: Check if Build Action in the image properties is set to Content.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but found a solution. Please add the following to the `manifest.xml` file:

```
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>abc</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of 
   the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="abc" />
<IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/add-in-icon-lo-res.png"/>
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/add-in-icon-hi-res.png"/>
```

Resolution for the image should be Iconurls 64 x 64 pixels with 8 bit depth in png and for HighResolutionIconUrl 128 x 128 pixels

Comment: for me the root cause was a nginx setting having `Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";` this Cache-Control header set to the incoming requests which caused the icon not to show on Outlook2016

Answer (score 0):

try replacing '~remoteAppUrl' with localhost:[port number]. When you publish the app, this needs to be changed to the host and port number

Answer (score -1):

```
<CustomTab id="MyTab">
        <Group id="Raporty.MyTab.GroupPabcd">
            <Label resid="Raporty.MyTab.GroupPabcd.Label" />
......

            <Label resid="Raporty.MyTab.TabLabel" />
```

That is corect code for manifest.

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.